# Android BLE GATT_ERROR(133) on connecting to device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am trying to connect to a BLE device using the MAC address.

```
BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(rememberedDeviceAddress)
bluetoothDevice.connectGatt(context, false, bluetoothGattCallback);
```

I get a callback in `BluetoothGattCallback.onConnectionStateChange` with `status = 133` and `newState = 2` **even when my BLE device is switched off.**

newState = 2 refers to `BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED` which means that i am connected to the device and status = 133 is GATT_ERROR (instead of status = 0 SUCCESS)

I do not get the **Failed to register callback** error.

Device : One plus one (Android 4.4)

Any pointers on what might be causing this issue would be helpful.

Note: Issue does not happen on all device. Everything seems to be working fine on Nexus 5 with Android 5.0

Please find below the stack trace:

```
03-06 13:00:11.994: D/BluetoothGatt(26771): registerApp()
03-06 13:00:11.994: D/BluetoothGatt(26771): registerApp() - UUID='uuid comes here'
03-06 13:00:12.004: D/BluetoothGatt(26771): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
03-06 13:00:42.004: D/BluetoothGatt(26771): onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=5 device='device id comes here'
```

Comment: Have a look at the answer suggested for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280402/every-connection-request-is-being-treated-as-direct-connect-request-android-bl

Comment: Could you figure this out? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Certain devices require Bluetooth LE interactions to be run on the UI thread. So I would recommend trying something like this:

```
// Create handler for main thread where mContext is application context
mHandler = new Handler(mContext.getMainLooper());
...
// Connect to BLE device from mHandler
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    mBTGatt = mBTDevice.connectGatt(mContext, false, mGattCallback);
}
});
```

Of course you could use Activity.runOnUiThread as well. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23478737

Comment: Seriously? everything I've been reading says not to run gatt operations on the UI thread.