# How to read two BLE characteristics of two services at the same interface page?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I am trying to manage my temperature service and LED service of my BLE device at the same Android interface. However, whenever I try to turn the LED on, the app dies, and I don't know how to fix this (I am not good at either Java or BLE).

I have all of the UUIDs of the characteristics and services I need. I am trying to create two BluetoothGattCharacteristic

```
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristicCTRL2;
```

It works fine when I call the temperature characteristic and get the temperature measurement. However, the app dies whenever I try to turn the LED on /call the LED characteristic.

```
10-30 08:48:33.026 1033-1033/com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt, PID: 1033
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic.setValue(byte[])' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt.AutoConnectActivity.turnLEDon(AutoConnectActivity.java:71)
                                                                                   at com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt.AutoConnectActivity$6.onClick(AutoConnectActivity.java:264)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
                                                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19754)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5219)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

The following code is how I transfer all characteristics & services together.

```
 // Loops through available Characteristics.
        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic : gattCharacteristics) {
            charas.add(gattCharacteristic);
            if ( gattCharacteristic.getUuid().equals(UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CTRL_2))){ //CTRL_2 is the UUID of my LED characteristic
                Log.e(TAG, "GattCharacteristics= " + gattCharacteristic.getUuid());
                Intent intent = new Intent(DeviceControlActivity.this, AutoConnectActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("character_id", "F000AA01-0451-4000-B000-000000000000"); //UUID of my temperature characteristic
                intent.putExtra("service_id", "F000AA00-0451-4000-B000-000000000000");//UUID of my temperature service
                intent.putExtra("address", mDeviceAddress);
                intent.putExtra("ctrl2_character_id", gattCharacteristic.getUuid().toString()); //UUID of my LED characteristics
                intent.putExtra("ctrl2_service_id", gattCharacteristic.getService().getUuid().toString());//UUID of my LED service
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

The part I fail is the function that I try to turn LED on.

```
public boolean turnLEDon()
    {

    byte[] value = {(byte)1};
    characteristicCTRL2.setValue(value);//This is the line I failed

    boolean status = mBluetoothLeService.mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristicCTRL2);

    return status;
};
```

The following is my complete code of trying to manipulate two characteristics at the same interface.

```
package com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt;



public class AutoConnectActivity extends Activity {
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic;
private BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristicCTRL2;
private String address;
private UUID serviceId;
private UUID charId;
private UUID ctrl2ServiceId;
private UUID ctrl2CharId;
private TextView debugText;
private Button startBtn;
private Button stopBtn;
private Button ctrlStartBtn;
private Button ctrlStopBtn;
private Timer timer = new Timer();
private boolean started = false;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private String Entry;
private File file;
private boolean check= true;


private BluetoothLeService mBluetoothLeService;



public boolean turnLEDon()
{

    byte[] value = {(byte)1};
    characteristicCTRL2.setValue(value);//This is the line I failed

    boolean status = mBluetoothLeService.mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristicCTRL2);

    return status;
};
public boolean turnLEDoff()
{

    byte[] value = {(byte)0};
    characteristicCTRL2.setValue(value);

    boolean status = mBluetoothLeService.mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristicCTRL2);

    return !status;
};

private TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        mBluetoothLeService.connect(address);
    }
};


// Code to manage Service lifecycle.
private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
        mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
            finish();
        }
        mBluetoothLeService.connect(address);
        List<BluetoothGattService> list = mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices();
        for(BluetoothGattService s : list){
            if(s.getUuid().compareTo(serviceId) == 0){
                if (check==true) {
                    characteristic = s.getCharacteristic(charId);
                    mBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
                }


                return;
            }
            if(s.getUuid().compareTo(ctrl2ServiceId) == 0){

                if(check==false) {
                    characteristicCTRL2 = s.getCharacteristic(ctrl2CharId);
                }

                return;
            }
        }
        mBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
        Log.e(TAG, "not find device");
        debugText.setText("not find device");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        mBluetoothLeService = null;
    }
};

private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        debugText.setText(action);
        if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            // if temperature measurement
            if (check==true){
            mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristic);}
            // if control LED
            if(check==false){
            mBluetoothLeService.readCharacteristic(characteristicCTRL2);
                turnLEDon();

            }

        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action))

        {
            if (check==false) {
            String CTRL_Status = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA);
            adapter.add("CTRL Status: " + CTRL_Status + "     " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

            turnLEDoff();
                mBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
            }
        if(check==true) {
            String temperature = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA);
            adapter.add("Temperature: " + temperature + "°C     " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

                Entry = address + "," + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString() + "," + temperature.toString() + "\n";

                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
                    out.write(Entry.getBytes());
                    out.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.autoconnect);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    address = intent.getStringExtra("address");
    serviceId = UUID.fromString(intent.getStringExtra("service_id"));
    charId = UUID.fromString(intent.getStringExtra("character_id"));
    ctrl2ServiceId = UUID.fromString(intent.getStringExtra("ctrl2_service_id"));
    Log.e(TAG, " CTRL2 SERVICE: " + ctrl2ServiceId);
    ctrl2CharId = UUID.fromString(intent.getStringExtra("ctrl2_character_id"));
    Log.e(TAG, " CTRL2 CHARAC: " + ctrl2CharId);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.address_txt)).setText(address);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.service_txt)).setText(serviceId.toString());
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.char_txt)).setText(charId.toString());
    debugText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.debug_txt);
    startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_btn);
    stopBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop_btn);
    ctrlStartBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ctrl_start_btn);
    ctrlStopBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ctrl_stop_btn);
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.result_list);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(started) return;
            started = true;
            check=true;

            //External Storage
            String state;
            state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File Dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/MeasurementDataFile");
                if (!Dir.exists()) {
                    Dir.mkdir();
                }
                file = new File(Dir, "Temperature.csv");

            }
            if (check==true){
            timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000 * 5); }
        }
    });

    stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!started) return;
            started = false;
            check=true;

            timer.cancel();
        }
    });

    ctrlStartBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            mBluetoothLeService.connect(address);
            check=false;
            if(started) return;
            started = true;



            Toast.makeText (getBaseContext(), "Turn CTRL 1 ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.e(TAG, " On?: " + turnLEDon());

        }
    });

    ctrlStopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //mBluetoothLeService.connect(address);
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!started) return;
            started = false;
            check=false;

            Log.e(TAG, " Off?: " + turnLEDoff());
            Toast.makeText (getBaseContext(), "Turn CTRL 1 OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(this, BluetoothLeService.class);
    bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, DeviceControlActivity.makeGattUpdateIntentFilter());
    if (mBluetoothLeService != null) {
        final boolean result = mBluetoothLeService.connect(address);
        Log.d(TAG, "Connect request result=" + result);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. All BLE calls are asynchronous. This is really pain-in-neck, but we have what we have. So you cannot just write:

   *{
   boolean status = writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
   return status;
   }*

and hope all will be ok. In this case, you obtain a result of the *writeCharacteristic* instruction only, but not the real write operation result! For the last, you need to register the part of your code as *BluetoothGattCallback* descendant and read  *OnCharacteristicWrite* event, where you can really know the result of your write operation.

2. All BLE read-write operations should be done in a strict one-by-one sequence and from main app thread only.
3. Different devices have different capabilities and productivity, so you can obtain different results - IMHO, this is less strange, than Google's decision to realize BLE stack in this manner :)

Pretty BLE guide for Android can be found here: https://droidcon.de/sites/global.droidcon.cod.newthinking.net/files/media/documents/practical_bluetooth_le_on_android_0.pdf

**Edit**

The link above is broken but the other one can be found here:
https://speakerdeck.com/erikhellman/practical-bluetooth-low-energy-on-android

Comment: Not sure how this relates to the question "why do I get a null pointer exception?" but what you write is otherwise mostly correct except that you need to execute gatt operations on the main thread (there is no such requirement).

Comment: @Emil, yes, it's not requirement, it's just recommendation, which can help to avoid some ugly issues, like error 133 ( e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136103/android-bluetooth-error-133?noredirect=1&lq=1 )

Comment: I think I am still not sure what to do with my code. My turnLEDon and turnLEDoff functions work find when I only call one LED characteristic once, but not I wanna use one button to trigger both my LED characteristics and temperature characteristics. My code is based on the sample code BluetoothLeGatt (imported from Android Studio), so I basically have everything covered in the PDF file. Could you please help clarify what I should do a little bit more?

Comment: The BLE guide link is broken.